# Generating multiple dynamic rows of html table using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to create rows in a table dynamically depending on the content in the XML. In the below code I am trying to create a row(`<tr>`) with 5 columns. After 5 columns are filled, I want to create a new row.

A row can only contain 5 columns as per the below code. If i apply the XSL on the XML, I get an error displaying

> XSLT compile error. The 'tr' start tag on line 574 does not match the end tag of 'xsl:when'. Line 578, position 7.

```
570:<table>
571:    <xsl:for-each select="/alert/account_links/account_links_info">
572:                <xsl:choose>
573:                <xsl:when test="position() mod 5 = 1">
574:                    <tr>
575:                        <td>
576:                            <xsl:value-of select="account_id"/>
577:                        </td>                           
578:                </xsl:when>
579:                <xsl:when test="position() mod 5 = 0">
580:                    <td>
581:                        <xsl:value-of select="account_id"/>
582:                    </td>
583:                    </tr>
584:                </xsl:when>
585:                <xsl:otherwise>
586:                    <td>
587:                        <xsl:value-of select="account_id"/>
588:                    </td>
589:                </xsl:otherwise>
590:                </xsl:choose>
591:                </xsl:for-each>         
592:            </table>
```

Input Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<alert>
  <account_links>
    <account_links_info>
      <account_id>1</account_id>
    </account_links_info>
    <account_links_info>
      <account_id>2</account_id>
    </account_links_info>
    <account_links_info>
      <account_id>3</account_id>
    </account_links_info>
    <account_links_info>
      <account_id>4</account_id>
    </account_links_info>
    <account_links_info>
      <account_id>5</account_id>
    </account_links_info>
  </account_links>
</alert>
```

Can some one help me how to go ahead with this?

Comment: Your "XML" is not well-formed: it's missing a closing tr element after the closing td on line 577, and it's missing an opening tr element before the opening td on line 580. Even then, the structure being generated isn't a valid XHTML table. It would help if you posted a sample of what you wanted to achieve (preferably with a sample of what your input is).

Comment: Nobody can help you without a sample of your input and desired output.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<alert>
  <account_links>
    <account_links_info>
      <account_id>1</account_id>
    </account_links_info>
    <account_links_info>
      <account_id>2</account_id>
    </account_links_info>
    <account_links_info>
      <account_id>3</account_id>
    </account_links_info>
    <account_links_info>
      <account_id>4</account_id>
    </account_links_info>
    <account_links_info>
      <account_id>5</account_id>
   </account_links_info>
</alert>

Comment: I want to know how to write the XSL code to display the account id;s in above xml in html table where each row contains 5 columns....

Comment: Please edit your post to include the input XML, don't add it as a comment.  BTW, the XML in the comment is not well-formed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
<table>
       <xsl:for-each select="/alert/account_links/account_links_info[position()mod5=1]">
        <xsl:variable name = "current-pos" select="(position()-1) * 5+1"/>
        <tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="../account_links_info[position()&gt;=$current-pos and position() &lt; $current-pos+5]" >
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="account_id"/>
            </td>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>           
       </xsl:for-each>         
</table>
```

(the idea is to have an outer loop for the `<tr>` output running through every fifth `account_links_info element`, and an inner loop filling the rows with the `account_id` values).

Answer (score 2):

XSLT instructions produce nodes on a result tree, not lexical begin and end tags. Outputting a node is a single operation, you can't divide it into two operations writing half a node each. So your thinking should be "for every five nodes in the input I want to produce a node in the output", which leads naturally to a construct such as

```
<xsl:for-each select="*[position() mod 5 = 1]">
```

Don't be seduced into using disable-output-escaping for this. It's poison. It breaks the clean architectural boundary between the transformation engine and the serialized, which means that your stylesheet can't be cleanly deployed and reused in an arbitrary pipeline (which is the reason it won't work in Firefox, in case you're interested in the practical consequences).

Answer (score 0):

Because you are setting the `<tr>` and `</tr>` tags in different locations, you must output them as text to keep it valid XML for the XSL file.  Also, you should output the `</tr>` tag when it is the last element in the table or the last row may not be closed:

```
<table>
  <xsl:for-each select="/alert/account_links/account_links_info">
    <xsl:if test="position()mod5=1">
      <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;tr&gt;</xsl:text>          
    </xsl:if>
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="account_id"/>
    </td>
    <xsl:if test="position()mod5=0 or position()=last()">
      <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;/tr&gt;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>        
  </xsl:for-each>
</table>
```

Comment: And this is not one of them. It's horrible.

Comment: @Michael Kay: think you are right; hope my solution meets your expectations better.

Comment: @Michael Kay: From your comment in your solution, what part won't work in Firefox?  Isn't the output of the transformation a text file that is interpreted as XML the next step down the line?  Also, any chance you can include new XSL tags for this purpose in the future:  <xsl:startTag name="tr"/>, <xsl:endTag name="tr"/>     :)   P.S.  Enjoyed your XSLT 2.0 book.  Sorry I've been drawn to the dark side ;)

Comment: @Michael Kay: Never-mind the first question, I see Firefox skips the intermediate text step and goes directly to the DOM, and thus can't handle it properly.